# Order the array key position by group in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I googled and found array key change only by index. But what I want is by group.
There are 3 groups in the sample array. 
1. Attendances
2. MainGroups and
3. Masters

My input is like that.

```
array(
    (int) 12 => 'Attendances',
    (int) 15 => '_master_add',
    (int) 16 => '_master_full_month',
    (int) 17 => '_master_edit_grade',
    (int) 18 => '_master_edit',
    (int) 19 => '_master_delete',
    (int) 20 => '_master_upload_csv',
    (int) 36 => 'MainGroups',
    (int) 39 => '_master_add',
    (int) 40 => '_master_edit',
    (int) 41 => '_master_delete',
    (int) 43 => 'Masters',
    (int) 46 => '_master_add',
    (int) 47 => '_master_edit',
    (int) 48 => '_master_delete',
    (int) 52 => '_master_stop'
)
```

The output I want is 
1. Attendances
2. Masters and
3. MainGroups

```
array(
    (int) 12 => 'Attendances',
    (int) 15 => '_master_add',
    (int) 16 => '_master_full_month',
    (int) 17 => '_master_edit_grade',
    (int) 18 => '_master_edit',
    (int) 19 => '_master_delete',
    (int) 20 => '_master_upload_csv',
    (int) 43 => 'Masters',
    (int) 46 => '_master_add',
    (int) 47 => '_master_edit',
    (int) 48 => '_master_delete',
    (int) 52 => '_master_stop'
    (int) 36 => 'MainGroups',
    (int) 39 => '_master_add',
    (int) 40 => '_master_edit',
    (int) 41 => '_master_delete',
)
```

Comment: do you want to reorder the array in custom order?

Comment: Do you need single array to two dimensional array By (Attendances, Masters,MainGroups) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, I want to reorder the array in custom order.

Comment: Mani, I need only single array. Not dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

There are no groups. Maybe you see them because you know what the values mean, php only sees a bunch of numbers as keys with a value attatched.

I see two options to solve your problem.

1. Create a an array that containt the numbers of the keys your 'groups' refer to:

   `$keys=array(`

   `"Attendances'=>array(15,16,1718,19,20),`

   `'Masters'=>array(46,47,48,52),`

   `'MainGroups'=>array(39,40,41)`

   `);`

Now you can refer to a 'group value by calling

`$myarray['Attendances'[0]]` (for $myarray[15] ==> '_master_add')

This only works if the keys are always the same.

Your second option is to resturcture your array so it really contains groups:

```
array(
    'Attendances'= array(
        (int) 1 => '_master_add',
        (int) 2 => '_master_full_month',
        (int) 3 => '_master_edit_grade',
        (int) 4 => '_master_edit',
        (int) 5 => '_master_delete',
        (int) 6 => '_master_upload_csv'
    ),
    'MainGroups'=>array(
       (int) 1 => '_master_add',
       (int) 2 => '_master_edit',
       (int) 3 => '_master_delete',
       (int) 4 => 'Masters',
       (int) 5 => '_master_add',
       (int) 6 => '_master_edit',
       (int) 7 => '_master_delete',
       (int) 8 => '_master_stop'
    ),
   'Masters'=>array(
       (int) 1 => '_master_add',
       (int) 2 => '_master_edit',
       (int) 3 => '_master_delete',
       (int) 4 => '_master_stop'
   )
);
```

In that case you can call `$myarray['Attendances[1]']` for '_master_add'

**Edit**
After reading your comments, the following might work. It gives the output desired. But looping this array can only be done with a `foreach` to preserve the order.

**Edit 2**
Added a search for the keys of the 'group names' so you can create the order array without knowing the keys.

```
$my_array=array(... see above...);
$key1=array_search('Attendances',$my_array);
$key2=array_search('MainGroups',$my_array);
$key3=array_search('Masters',$my_array);

foreach($my_array as $k=>$v){
    if($k >= $key1 && $k<$key2){
        $group_1[]=$k;
        }
    elseif($k >= $key2 && $k<$key3){
        $group_2[]=$k;
        }
    else{
        $group_3[]=$k;
        }
    }

$order=array_merge($group_1,$group_3,$group_2);    
$new_array=array();

foreach($order as $key => $value){
    $new_array[$value]=$my_array[$value];
    }

echo '<pre>'.print_r($new_array,true).'<pre>';
```

Comment: Michel, thanks for the answer. But I'm sorry I can't change my input and I want the output as described in the question. Because, it's cakephp's ACL (Access Control List) authentication and changing the input is not possible for me.

Comment: Hi Michel, really thanks for the answers. But still I've missed to point out that the array I get is from the database and index is table's id so I don't know which index might be get. I can only depends on the array value rather than array index. So, first I think I've to write how to know the group depending on the value. Then how to change the order. But still can't think how to do that.

Comment: Ah, didn't get that. An `array_search()` for all the 'group names' might do the trick. If you have those keys, you can construct an array with the desired key-order.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input_arr = array(
    12 => 'Attendances',
    15 => '_master_add',
    16 => '_master_full_month',
    17 => '_master_edit_grade',
    18 => '_master_edit',
    19 => '_master_delete',
    20 => '_master_upload_csv',
    36 => 'MainGroups',
    39 => '_master_add',
    40 => '_master_edit',
    41 => '_master_delete',
    43 => 'Masters',
    46 => '_master_add',
    47 => '_master_edit',
    48 => '_master_delete',
    52 => '_master_stop'
);
$output_array = array();
$group_found = false;
$sort_arr = array('Attendances', 'Masters', 'MainGroups');

foreach ($sort_arr as $sort_group) {
    foreach ($input_arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($group_found == true || $value == $sort_group) {

            if ($group_found) {
                if (strpos($value, '_') !== false) {
                    $output_array[$key] = $value;
                } else {
                    $group_found = false;
                }
            }

            if ($value == $sort_group) {
                $group_found = true;
                $output_array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I got it by double looping and using new array rather than modifying in the input array. Thanks to Michel for I've got an idea for using new array for my problem.

```
debug($output_array);
array(
    (int) 12 => 'Attendances',
    (int) 15 => '_master_add',
    (int) 16 => '_master_full_month',
    (int) 17 => '_master_edit_grade',
    (int) 18 => '_master_edit',
    (int) 19 => '_master_delete',
    (int) 20 => '_master_upload_csv',
    (int) 43 => 'Masters',
    (int) 46 => '_master_add',
    (int) 47 => '_master_edit',
    (int) 48 => '_master_delete',
    (int) 52 => '_master_stop',
    (int) 36 => 'MainGroups',
    (int) 39 => '_master_add',
    (int) 40 => '_master_edit',
    (int) 41 => '_master_delete'
)
```